# ibm_db cannot be installed in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'm trying to install ibm_db in my Ubuntu 14.04 (I did have that package before but I had to format my computer). When:

```
pip install ibm_db
```

I get this error looking at "tail -n100 /home/nfs/user/.pip/pip.log"

```
copying tests/test_220_PersistentConn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_150_FetchAssocSelect_01.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_041_FetchTupleMany_01.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_060_Tables_01.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_120_FieldName.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_091_ConnmsgWrongUser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_200_MultipleRsltsetsUniformColDefs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_024_ForeignKeys.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_155_FetchAssocSelect_05.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_154_AllFetches.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_201_MultipleRsltsetsDiffColDefs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_003_NumAffectedRows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_createDropDB.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_045_FetchTupleBinaryData_01.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_260_FetchTupleMany_07.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_recreateDB.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/test_6561_InsertNULLValues.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

running egg_info

creating ibm_db.egg-info

writing ibm_db.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to ibm_db.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to ibm_db.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'ibm_db.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'ibm_db.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'clidriver'

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'ibm_db_dlls'

writing manifest file 'ibm_db.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

copying tests/pic1.jpg -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

copying tests/spook.png -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tests

running build_ext

building 'ibm_db' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/nfs/ruben/Downloads/dsdriver/./include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ibm_db.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ibm_db.o

ibm_db.c:26:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_ruben...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_ruben/ibm-db/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RuRqdo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ruben/ibm-db
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_ruben/ibm-db/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RuRqdo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ruben/ibm-db
```

What's happening with the package. Is the source link broken?

Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I see python-dev package is missed on your machine. Try to install it and re-install ibm_db. To install python-dev use following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y python-dev
```

Comment: installing ibm_db in a virtualenvironment still shows the error message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 99: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: when i do pip freeze, i get the ibm-db==2.0.5.1 inside the list, but still having problems installing it in a virtual env

Comment: Look like this issue is connected with locale settings on your machine. Try to set your locale explicitly, for example: export LC_ALL=C and try to re-install ibm_db.